# Error related to libraries

Tags: c++

i just write a fuzzy code with a fuzzylogic library(eFLL library). I used it in a linux environment and try to compile it with g++. i unziped the library in the g++ path. but these errors come to me and i do not know what are these for. i make a Makefile and try to solve the problem but nothing well happend. does anyone know how can i solve this problem?

a part of code is like this:

```
include <iostream.h>

#include "../FuzzyRule.h"

#include "../FuzzyComposition.h"

#include "../Fuzzy.h"


void setup(){

Fuzzy* fuzzy = new Fuzzy();

FuzzyInput* Threat = new FuzzyInput(1);


FuzzySet* lowThreat = new FuzzySet::FuzzySet(0, 1.875, 1.875, 3.75),
```

a part of errors are like this:

> fuzzycode2.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `Fuzzy::Fuzzy()'
>
> fuzzycode2.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to
>   `FuzzyInput::FuzzyInput(int)'
>
> fuzzycode2.cpp:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to
>   `FuzzySet::FuzzySet(float, float, float, float)'
>
> fuzzycode2.cpp:(.text+0xed): undefined reference to
>   `FuzzyIO::addFuzzySet(FuzzySet*)'
>
> fuzzycode2.cpp:(.text+0x129): undefined reference to
>   `FuzzySet::FuzzySet(float, float, float, float)'

Comment: Did you tell your linker to actually link to the library?

Comment: can you post the shell command that starts the compilation ?

Comment: `<iostream.h>`? You really want to ditch the books from the previous millenium!

Answer (score 2):

Including the headers into the C++ files isn't enough. You also need to specify the library file and possibly its location while linking, e.g.:

```
g++ your-files-go-here -o some-name -Llocation-of-the-library -llibrary-name
```

Looking at the page of this particular "library" it seems it consists of just a bunch of object files which you would need to put together into a library or include explicitly while linking.

Comment: This tries to link an executable from `mycode.cpp` alone. To only compile the code you need to use `g++ -c mycode.cpp`

Comment: I solved my problem by creating make file and use the "make" command.